# Highest-voted questions giving wrong results

Tags: bug, design

I was browsing the highest voted questions (Questions > Votes) on programmers, but noticed something extremely weird on page seven of the results.

> [image]

Going from questions with over a hundred votes to a question with two to four votes each? That can't possibly be right.

The top of page eight returns to >100 point questions, only to jump to two-point questions halfway through:

> [image]

What's going on? Please tell me I'm not going crazy.

It seems to happen on 15 questions/page, but not on 50 questions/page. It also doesn't seem to happen on Stack Overflow, so it might be specific to programmers.

Answer (score 2):

You are not crazy.  For me, I can see this on a few different pages.  Page [9, 15/view](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=9&sort=votes&pagesize=15) ranges from scores of 4 to 1.  Page [10, 15/view](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=10&sort=votes&pagesize=15) has 116 to 114, and then 1s and 0s. Page [11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=11&sort=votes&pagesize=15) has 116 to 111, and -4.  For what its worth, it starts getting wonky on page [7](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=7&sort=votes&pagesize=15) where it goes from 109 to 58 and then goes downhill from there.

Similar wonkiness can be seen on page [5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=votes&pagesize=30) and [6](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=6&sort=votes&pagesize=30) at 30/page. And page [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=3&sort=votes&pagesize=50) and [4](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=votes&pagesize=50) on 50/page.